# Which SE site is appropriate for questions about crowdsourcing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, crowdsourcing

I'm creating an online questionnaire using microtask crowdsourcing service e.g. Amazon Mechanical Turk, but I'm stuck with the questionnaire design that best suits my analysis.

I appreciate if you have a SE site recommendation for this type of crowdsourcing task design question.

**Edit:**
The questionnaire can be summarized as follows:
Workers watch several short time animations and answer which one is best.
I'm wondering the result would be different if all animations are aligned and presented at the same moment, or one by one.

Comment: Can you put in a sample question? I am not sure if it is too broad or opinion based to start with.

Comment: I suspect this would be closed as opinion based everywhere on Stack Exchange i.e. there is nowhere here you can ask such a question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I expect there are some scientific researches aiming at accurate survey on crowdsourcing. I hope I could know the best way to get accurate results based on such studies.

Answer (score 0):

This could be interpreted as a User Experience question, so you could try [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/):

> If you have a question about
>
> ...
>
> - UX issues that can be solved with expert advice or existing research
> - Questions about HCI and user research

At the moment, the question is still vague and would best be enriched with some examples of what you're trying to achieve.